Desplegar un proyecto utilizando Render
Esta es la estructura de mi codigo:

Pero me sale este error cada vez que intento desplegarlo en los servidores de render, necesito ayuda soy junior y siempre me encuentro con un nuevo desafio, espero sus respuestas. Muchas gracias, este es mi codigo de error:
